# Using lightbox in Cakephp

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, lightbox, lightbox2

i am trying to use lightbox effects on my image.
for that i am just trying on single image and here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php echo $this->Html->script('lightbox/lightbox.js');?>
    <?php echo $this->Html->script('lightbox/scriptaculous.js?load=effects');?>
    <?php echo $this->Html->script('lightbox/prototype.js');?>
    <?php echo $this->Html->css('lightbox/lightbox.css');?>
</head>
<body>

    <a href='<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>images/home/logo.png' title="gotta go?" rel="lightbox"> 
        <?php echo $this->Html->image("home/logo.png"); ?>  
    </a>
    <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
</body>
```

in Inspect Elements link generate like this

```
<a href="/cakephp/app/webroot/images/home/logo.png" title="gotta go?" rel="lightbox"> 
    <img src="/cakephp/app/webroot/images/home/logo.png" alt="">  
</a>
```

yes all the file name and locations are correct.In view page source i can open all 3 scripts 1 css

And i have tried this in corephp it works good i can use lightbox effects but it's not working in my cakephp project

When i click on image it just shows image like we do right click and view image.
May be i am doing something wrong.
Thnx in advance for any help.

Comment: Maybe add lightbox.js after prototype.js, and your path to images is incorrect

Comment: yes i tried as you say.And if my path of image is wrong then how can i see my image when i click?it's showing image as i said in my question

Comment: What version of CakePHP you use it?

Comment: @Salines i am using cakephp 2.7.1

Comment: Not sure if that is related to your lightbox problem, but I think your path to the image files is looking strange: `/cakephp/app/webroot/` should not be part of the image url, because these folders are usually invisible in the browser request due to htaccess rewriting in your CakePHP application...